# How to get the ALL max or min values between two dates

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a database table with 2 fields; `Date` and `Value`. The `Date` field stores daily dates, without duplication and `Value` field stores, the daily value of an instrument. This value is inserted into the field Value. This value can be either positive of negative, ranging from -15 to 15, right now.

Based on this a graph is plotted keeping a center line at ZERO. So far, I have done this. [image]

Now, I am facing a problem while generating a report. Say, I want to get the list of dates when the value line start rising/falling between 2 dates. For  example: Between 10-jan and 2-Feb, list the dates when either the value starts rising/falling.

I know simple SQL won't help me much. Can someone suggest me where to start from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
Sub Main()
        Dim pairs = New List(Of Pair)

        ' pairs ordered by date
        pairs.Add(New Pair() With {.Date = #1/1/2016#, .Value = 1})
        pairs.Add(New Pair() With {.Date = #1/2/2016#, .Value = 2})
        pairs.Add(New Pair() With {.Date = #1/30/2016#, .Value = 3}) ' <-- high peak
        pairs.Add(New Pair() With {.Date = #2/1/2016#, .Value = 2})
        pairs.Add(New Pair() With {.Date = #2/2/2016#, .Value = 1})
        pairs.Add(New Pair() With {.Date = #2/10/2016#, .Value = -2}) ' <-- low peak
        pairs.Add(New Pair() With {.Date = #3/1/2016#, .Value = 1})
        pairs.Add(New Pair() With {.Date = #3/2/2016#, .Value = 2})
        pairs.Add(New Pair() With {.Date = #3/26/2016#, .Value = 3}) ' <-- high peak
        pairs.Add(New Pair() With {.Date = #4/1/2016#, .Value = 2})
        pairs.Add(New Pair() With {.Date = #4/5/2016#, .Value = 1}) ' <-- low peak
        pairs.Add(New Pair() With {.Date = #4/10/2016#, .Value = 2})


        For i As Integer = 0 To pairs.Count - 1
            If ((i > 0) AndAlso (i < pairs.Count - 1)) Then
                Dim previousPair As Pair = pairs(i - 1)
                Dim nextPair As Pair = pairs(i + 1)
                Dim currentPair As Pair = pairs(i)

                currentPair.IsPeak = ((previousPair.Value < currentPair.Value) AndAlso (currentPair.Value > nextPair.Value)) OrElse ((previousPair.Value > currentPair.Value) AndAlso (currentPair.Value < nextPair.Value))
            End If
        Next

        For Each p In pairs
            If p.IsPeak Then
                Console.WriteLine(p)
            End If
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub


    Private Class Pair
        Public Property [Date] As DateTime
        Public Property Value As Integer
        Public Property IsPeak As Boolean

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy} {1}", [Date], Value)
        End Function
    End Class
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple method would be to open the table sorted by date.

Now, loop through the records. When moving to the next record, compare *the difference between current Value and Value of the previous record* with *the difference between Values of the previous two records*. If the slopes differ, you have a hit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made it. Your suggestion did helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you should store tick time in database
you can easily convert tick time to date and generate report from/to date with ticktime

for store "now ticktime" in database 
1-you should store ticktime variable in database date field:

```
long ticktime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
```

2-then for generate report from database Between 10-jan-1998 and 2-Feb-1998

```
DateTime from_dt = new DateTime(1998, 01, 10);
DateTime to_dt = new DateTime(1998, 02, 02);
```

3-sql query ("date is table column or field")

```
select * from tablex where(tablex.date>=from_dt.Ticks and tablex.date<=to_dt.Ticks)
```

Comment: There will only one entry per day. Hence time not required. And above all, I need the MAX and MIN values, NOT all values. The dates marked with blue lines will only be the output.